# English-Russian dictionary

Tags: gratis, translation, english

I'm looking for a free English-Russian dictionary for offline use in my project. It can be txt/csv/xml/sql database, I don't care.

If the translations come with additional descriptions/examples that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long, long time ago I found several such databases to use with a dictionary application I wrote for  myself. The only link to them I have right now is on my personal website, which is [here](http://lazunin.com/vocab_en.html). They are in text format, one entry per line, [word][two spaces][translation]. There are Apresyan, Korolev and Mueller English-Russian dictionaries (Mueller even has phonetic readings).

Comment: Is this legal, or did you just copy 'something from somewhere'? What's the license?

Comment: @JanDoggen I found them on some linguistic forums. Those are all quite old dictionaries, made in the Soviet Union. About the Mueller's I am pretty sure it's in public domain now, the author died in 1941. At least the edition used for the file by the link - Wikipedia says, new editions get printed even these days, the situation may be different with them. I read somewhere that the other two are also effectively in public domain, because nobody holds a copyright, but I can't attest the reliability of that claim.